# Data wrangling in R with dplyr: How do I consolidate rows? United States Census data

Tags: r, categorical-data, descriptive-statistics, sum, duplicate-records

I am analysing population projection data from the United States census and I need to present population estimates by race/ethnicity for each year from 2020 to 2029. The US census separates Asian-Americans from Pacific Islander-Americans (which is good!) but, unfortunately, my analysis cannot be so granular because I need to link it to another, less granular data set. Additionally, the Census has an "Origin" variable for Americans' Hispanic or non-Hispanic ethnicity. When I downloaded the CSV file from the census website, I created a new "race_eth" variable from the Census's "RACE" and "ORIGIN" variables to consolidate them, then imported the data into R for analysis. However, because the data were originally more granular in Excel, they have been kept granular in R. Meaning, for example, that for the population projection for people ages 40-44 in the non-Hispanic Asian-American/Pacific Islander group in the year 2025, there are two values: 1703313 and 50487. I want these two values to be summed together, such that there is only one value (1703313 + 50487) for Asian-American/Pacific Islanders aged 40-44 in the year 2025. I attempted this in dplyr using the code below, but have had no luck so far:

```
Census_pop_raw <- read.csv(file = "US Census 2017 National Pop Projections copy.csv", 
                            header = T, 
                            na.strings = c(" ")
   )

# PROBLEM: Due to the origin variable in Excel, and the fact that Asians and Pacific Islanders were separated, our consolidated groups have repeats.
Census_pop <- Census_pop_raw 
Census_pop$race_eth <- as.factor(Census_pop$ï..race_eth)
Census_pop <- Census_pop %>%
  group_by(race_eth, YEAR) %>%
  filter(YEAR >= 2020, YEAR < 2030) %>%
  select(-ï..race_eth, -TOTAL_POP)
```

"ï..race_eth" is how the race_eth variable I created in Excel got imported into R.

I have attached two images - one of the Excel document and one of the data in R.[image: Excel data showing duplicated years for Non-Hispanic Asian/Pacific Islander]

[image: The same data, showing duplicated years, in R]

Thank you in advance for your patience in reading my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```r
Census_pop %>%
  filter(YEAR >= 2020, YEAR < 2030) %>%
  group_by(race_eth, YEAR) %>%
  summarise(POP_AGG = sum(TOTAL_POP))
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked! I was able to apply it to each of the age categories. Thanks very much for your help.